# Bonferroni correction gives weird results in R

Tags: nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, dunn-test

I have this dataset:

| Treatment | data |
| --- | --- |
| T1 | 0 |
| T1 | 0 |
| T1 | 0 |
| T10 | 0 |
| T10 | 0 |
| T10 | 0 |
| T11 | 0.2 |
| T11 | 0.2 |
| T11 | 0.2 |
| T12 | 0 |
| T12 | 0 |
| T12 | 0 |
| T2 | 0.7 |
| T2 | 0.6 |
| T2 | 0.6 |
| T3 | 0.8 |
| T3 | 0.7 |
| T3 | 0.8 |
| T4 | 0.3 |
| T4 | 0.3 |
| T4 | 0.4 |
| T5 | 0 |
| T5 | 0 |
| T5 | 0 |
| T6 | 0.7 |
| T6 | 0.7 |
| T6 | 0.5 |
| T7 | 0 |
| T7 | 0 |
| T7 | 0 |
| T8 | 0.8 |
| T8 | 0.7 |
| T8 | 0.8 |
| T9 | 0 |
| T9 | 0 |
| T9 | 0 |

After Scheirer–Ray–Hare test with significant results, I did Dunn test with Bonferroni correction for multiple comparisons. `Code: Test = dunnTest(Data ~ Treatment, data=dataset, method="bh")`. Here are some results:

| Comparison | Z | P.unadj | P.adj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| T1 - T3 | -2.92771374 | 0.003414643 | 0.01878053 |
| T10 - T3 | -2.92771374 | 0.003414643 | 0.02048786 |
| T11 - T3 | -1.61958633 | 0.105321169 | 0.21722491 |
| T12 - T3 | -2.92771374 | 0.003414643 | 0.02253664 |
| T2 - T3 | -0.66444567 | 0.506405109 | 0.74272749 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| T1 - T9 | 0.00000000 | 1.000000000 | 1.000000000 |
| T10 - T9 | 0.00000000 | 1.000000000 | 1.000000000 |
| T11 - T9 | 1.30812742 | 0.190830096 | 0.38166019 |
| T12 - T9 | 0.00000000 | 1.000000000 | 1.000000000 |
| T2 - T9 | 2.26326807 | 0.023619169 | 0.08204554 |
| T3 - T9 | 2.92771374 | 0.003414643 | 0.11268321 |

As you can see, P after adjustment gives very weird results. For example, T1-T3 is 0.01878053 (significant), but T3-T9 is 0.11268321 (nonsignificant) even though T1 and T9 had exactly the same data (all zero), and P before adjustment are exactly the same as well.

Am I doing it wrong somewehere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the package docs I presume you are using ([dunn.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dunn.test/versions/1.3.5/topics/dunn.test)) the method 'bh' is the 'Benjamini-Hochberg adjustment' not the bonferroni correction. This might explain why you get different adjusted values for tests with the same p values, as this method orders the tests and then adjusts values based on the ordering. I'm not sure exactly how this method deals with duplicate p values, but it may be the case that T1-T3 is arbitrarily assigned earlier in the ordering than T3-T9 and so they get different adjusted p values.

Comment: Oh, I see. I used the code from somewhere else so I assumed it was bonferroni. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to consider using the Holm method instead as this has more power and still controls the familywise error rate.

Comment: Also if this has answered your question please consider accepting the answer :)